# Website looks bigger on server than on localhost

Tags: html, css, meta

I have seen similar questions asked, but usually the issue people have is the opposite of mine.

I am working on my online portfolio and for some reason when I upload the website to the server in the desktop version all the assets are larger than what they are when viewed on localhost. That is not an issue when I look at the website on mobile devices, both localhost and server versions are identical as they should be.

For example, an image that is set to 300px in width will display as 360px. The devtools will say that the image is 300px wide but if I take a screenshot and measure it in photoshop I can see that it is considerably bigger (it is obvious even without measuring it in photoshop). It doesn't just happen to the images but to everything else, fonts, sizing of individual areas like the nav bar etc... It's driving me nuts!

Below are two screenshots, the first of my website in localhost, the second from the server. You can see from the devtools that the image in question is declared to be 300px wide and 300px high in both instances but the difference between the two is clear.

[image]
[image]

People with similar issues have talked about the browser zoom being responsible, but that is not the case as I have checked. I thought maybe it could be the viewport meta in the header but that also makes no difference.

The meta I am using is:

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1

which by what I can tell is what is recommended.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So -- Troubleshooting .. Have you gone through the headers and responses with a fine toothed comb?  There are more than just `viewport` headers that can affect the display of a site.  Albeit rare ..

Comment: It's not anything stupid like you had manually zoomed in when visiting your production environment? I've done that myself a few times. Some browsers are "smart" and remembers zoom, even if you closed the tab.

Comment: Can you show me an example of a header that could affect the display state? As far as I can see everything is in order and the fact that it works perfectly on mobile devices but not on desktop is very confusing.

Comment: @ Rickard Elimää - No, I can see in the browser settings that the zoom is set to 100% in both cases. That was the first thing I checked as it is the issue that people ran into when they have a similar problem, except that instead of their site looking bigger online it looks smaller.

Comment: @Rickard - My god, it was the localhost window that was zoomed out. I had all my attention on the server site that I didn't see it. Yes, I am a huge tit. Problem remains though, why are the assets on the desktop view bigger than they should be?